# -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set, Issue with maven 3.3.3 and eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-luna

i get this error while i try to install maven with maven project (was running before) 
[image]

i use maven 3.3.3 and eclipse luna.
Thanx in advance

Comment: in Window-> Preference -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Edit->Add a new VM argument called  -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME

Comment: Thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: if it helped please upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update m2e plugin in eclipse. This will resolve the problem, too.

Go to Help Menu > Eclipse Marketplace > Installed, and click on m2e Update button.

Comment: This may prevent future problems because of version mismatching.